# Module has no exported member 'IonicNativePlugin', Ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am trying to get camera, file, filepath and transfer plugin working and I am getting this error for each of these,

```
Module 'node_modules/@ionic-native/core/index' has no exported member 'IonicNativePlugin'
```

I got the latest Ionic2 version.

package.json file as requested

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/file": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
"fast-sha256": "1.0.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
"ionic-native": "^3.5.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"sha256": "0.2.0",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"ts-md5": "1.2.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"

devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"

"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"

"cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Work: An Ionic project"
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: Added in first post

Comment: Your package json code has missing ending '}'

Comment: I deleted it just for this site to make it shorter, there is nothing missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, IonicNativePlugin was added in newer version of ionic-native/core, so I had to uninstall this one and install the newest one which is 3.6.1, and now plugin got exported and everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

IonicNativePlugin works with ionic-native / core latest version (3.6.1), so you have to update to the latest version.

Type this command in your project directory:

```
npm install @ionic-native/core --save
```

Problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/core
npm install --save @ionic-native/core@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/core
npm install --save @ionic-native/core@latest

Do this, and then close everything including command prompt and open again and run. Issue is solver

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your ts code would help more on this problem. Also since you said you have the latest angular2 I assume you are using ionic 3.x.x, would be more helpful if you provide your ionic info.

here is how you should import and use your Camera, File, FilePath native plugins.

First make sure you have installed the plugins:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera

$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file

$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-path
```

Then you import your plugins at your ***page ts*** like so :

```
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
```

Make sure you have also added the providers in your app.module.ts

```
//at the top import the plugins
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

...

//inject your plugins in the providers at the bottom of your app.module.ts
providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},  File, FilePath, Camera]
```

Comment: I did this, still my plugins can't import { IonicNativePlugin } from '@ionic-native/core';

Comment: Why you are importing IonicNativePlugin??

Comment: I am not doing this, plugins are trying to import this.

Comment: I suggest you delete your node_module folder and redo npm install on your project.

Comment: Ok will try that.