# Issue in handling Geolocation in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to access the device location using Geolocation in ionic2. Followed the ionic2 documentation here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/ . Added the packages

$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation

Below is my code.

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
....

constructor(private placesService:PlacesService,private navCtrl:NavController,private geolocation:Geolocation) {
  }
....

onLocateUser(){
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
      .then((locaton) => {
          console.log('Location Fetched Successfully');
        }).catch((eroor) => {
        console.log('Error getting Location',eroor);
      });
  }
```

And my package.json looks like as below

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionic-native": "^3.5.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "ak-places: An Ionic project"
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Typescript Error
Module '"D:/Ionic/ak-places/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/index"' has no exported member 'IonicNativePlugin'.
D:/Ionic/ak-places/node_modules/@ionic-native/geolocation/index.d.ts
import { IonicNativePlugin } from '@ionic-native/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `"ionic-native": "^3.5.0",` from your `package.json` and use latest `"@ionic-native/core": "3.5.0",`.After that run `npm i`.

Here is the official [**package.json**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json) file.

Hope you know how to implement native plugins as a provider.If you want, you can read more from [**official doc here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/).

Answer (score 0):

Finally its solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/43659149/5350407 . Changed ionic core version in package.json and then executed `npm install` command